# Are two function pointers to the same function always equal?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Does the C++ standard guarantee that two pointers to a function always compare equal? I understand that this will normally be true for non-inline functions. But if there is an inline function and a pointer to the function is created in two separate compilation units, will the linker merge the two instantiations, or is it allowed to emit duplicate functions?

If the answer to the above is "they are equal": Does this still hold if there is a common header with an inline function, and both the main program and a dynamically loaded plugin (shared object/DLL) create a pointer to the function?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Section §5.10/1 of the C++11 standard says:

> Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are
>   both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same
>   address

Two copies of the same `inline` function are still the same function. From an implementation point-of-view, the compiler will generate a copy of the function in each translation unit but the linker will then throw one of the copies away so only one is remaining.

By taking the address of a function you prevent it from being inlined (different from `inline`, which is more about avoiding violation of the One Definition Rule).

DLLs are outside the scope of the standard but only one copy of the function will remain in the binary image so getting the function address (e.g. `GetProcAddress`) from the DLL will get the same function pointer as code inside the DLL.

Comment: Your last point is correct only in the domain of a same process. If the DLL is "shared" by more processes, the function may have distinct addresses in the distinct processes (and the code in the DLL will see different addresses depending on which process is calling it, each viewing also a distinct "state"). Moreover, these "distinct addresses" may be "images" of a same physical resource (that will thus remain shared), while the "state" (data segment) will remain different.

Comment: I think your wording is quite confusing. The point is, when taking the address of a function, you never get an "inlined" copy. You get _the_ externally visible function definition. This can even be used to force instantiation of a function template even if it's not otherwise used.

Comment: @sehe: That's a reasonable approximation, but not necessarily true. Imagine a compiler with "tail inlining" - if the last statement of a function is `return f()`, inline the entire body of `f()` and perhaps put a small jump to skip some prologue code. You now have an inlined function f that is also independently callable. A function pointer can point to that inline copy. The standard, by not detailing implementation, allows this. With such oddities allowed, a concise wording is often subtly wrong.

Comment: @MSalters can you point me at a source that explicitely allows all this? Because, to be frank, I think the wording "taking the address of a function (template instance) always returns the address of the one _symbol with external linkage_ is pretty accurate.

Comment: @MSalters: That's not actually legal. Functions are external linkage; they have the same address across all TUs. Else, it would be impossible for function pointer template parameters to work (and the same reason why strings cannot be template parameters). A function pointer must point to an external linkage function which has the same address across all TUs.

Comment: @DeadMG: How would you notice? With my suggestion, there's still one unique address. It just so happens to lie _within_ another function, but lacking `sizeof(function)` there's no way you can determine that in portable code. IOW, sehe's statement essentially is "inlining and externally visible are mutually exclusive", which I dispute.

Answer (score 8):

> Does the C++ standard guarantee that two pointers to a function always
>   compare equal?

Yes, two pointers that point to the same function compare equal.

> Does this still hold if there is a common header with an inline
>   function, and both the main program and a dynamically loaded plugin
>   (shared object/DLL) create a pointer to the function?

Yes, per 7.1.2.p4

> An inline function with external linkage shall have the same address
>   in all translation units.

Comment: DLL's are technically Undefined Behavior. You can't just put it this simple. In practice, there's no reasonable way in which a compiler will know from which DLL it needs to import `std::map<std::string, std::complex<float>>::size()`, so you are likely to end up with multiple copies and multiple addresses.