# Function pointer values inside and outside a DLL

Tags: c, dll

The address of a function has a different value inside and outside a DLL.

Simplifying somewhat, I have the following code in a dll

```
  typedef struct Holder Holder;  /* Struct */
  typedef int (*pfn_t)(Holder*);   /* Function pointer */
  struct Holder { pfn_t pfn; }

  int IsSame( Holder *h ){ return h->pfn == IsSame; }
```

In a main program, I have:

```
  Holder h = { IsSame };
  assert( IsSame(&h) );
```

the assert fires!  The problem is that h.pfn is set to the address of the jump table in main.exe, whereas the code in the DLL is comparing this with the address of the function in the DLL.

Are there any magic annotations or linker options I can use to persuade the assert to not fire?

Note that this is on Windows.  The Posix shared library model is very different (and doesn't have this problem.)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134124/are-two-function-pointers-to-the-same-function-always-equal) could be related, especially the last paragraph of the accepted answer.

Comment: print address of each function. actually it should not fire

Comment: @Tibo:  If you mean "An inline function with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units." - Yes, that's what I want to be true ... but it isn't.  As noted in a comment, DLLs are Undefined Behaviour, and Microsoft compiler doesn't handle them perfectly.

Comment: @qwr:  I have inspected the function addresses inside a debugger.  They are different.  It would be nice if the assert didn't fire ... but it does.

Comment: @MartinBonner print those values. It can happen on such case function address in main refer to jump address. where it jumps to real function

Comment: @MartinBonner debug see if it is what i am assuming. there   must be linker option to make it not to do such.

Comment: There may well be linker options. Did you look in your compiler's documentation? Don't expect details from us if you conceal information like which linker you are using. Or how the DLL is compiled. And so on.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I've looked in the compiler documentation,  and it is not particularly illuminating.  "Conceal information" - Fair point!  It's Visual Studio 2008.  You will see that elsewhere I have linked to a discussion about MingW.  I now think this is more about the Windows ABI than the toolchain used.  (I've updated the question to indicate this is on Windows.)

Comment: Nothing to do with Windows ABI. Some linkers link directly to the exported function, some use JMP thunks. Nothing to do with ABI.

Comment: @MartinBonner why you want that assert?now you know that there is no problem behaving so. Plus you can use suggested ways. Either with loading by yourself or getting addreses of functions from one function inside dll(it be like interface)

Comment: My actual code has a test inside the DLL function which compares a function pointer in a structure with the address of the DLL function.  I need (for good but irrelevant reasons) that comparison to return true; in fact it is returning false.  The assert is just a simple way of demonstrating the problem in a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer:

http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/Direct-dll-linking-and-comparing-function-pointers-td2875.html#a2876

I need to use `__declspec(dllimport)` when I declare `IsSame` in the main program and `__declspec(dllexport)` when I define IsSame in the DLL in order to get the function pointers to be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be cause of that:

> function call goes through an extra JMP instruction .so it is relative address

Instead If you will use `LoadLibrary() GetProcAddress()` it will retrieve address of dll function.

Comment: No.  This is nothing to do with my problem.  I don't use incremental linking.  The problem is that the function is exported from the DLL via a .DEF file, and it is _that_ which introduces the jump table.

Comment: @MartinBonner I commented that in one of my comments.But I think that its name is incremental linking.  and I added getprocaddress as addition to solve this

Comment: Ah.  By incremental linking, I mean the ability to link in changes to an existing executable.  That is rather different to how a DLL is linked (although they both use an additional level of indirection.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this kind of function comparison you should use GetProcAddress or export an interface in your DLL that initialises any DLL function pointers to ensure that the addresses that you are comparing are the function address as seen by the module that it resides in rather than the trampoline from the .exe to the DLL which is all part of the Windows loader magic (TM).

Dynamic linkage relies on using trampolines which then jump to entries populated in the Export Address Table. A comparison to an imported function by identifier is only valid within the module it was linked in. Therefore the asumptions behind your code are wrong as they assume that address in the .exe is the address of the function. If you want a constant address of something you need to explicitly export it in the same way you would any data from that module and implicitly import it in any other modules (i.e. GetProcAddress)